# how to run a command for each subfolder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

i have a batch file to rename all pictures that found in a folder to series names like 0001.jpg 0002.jpg 003.jpg

the code of this batch file is :

```
set cnt=0
FOR /R d:\all\photos1\    %%a in (Graphic*.jpg) do call :renfile "%%a"
goto :eof

:renfile
set /a cnt += 1
set padCnt=0000%cnt%
ren %1 %padCnt:~-4%%~x1
```

the problem is that i have many folders and sub-folders inside my parent folder "all" so i had to make a batch file for each folder , so i need to make a batch file which will look at all folders and sub-folders inside my parent folder "all" and run that command that i have mentioned to rename the pictures inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
FOR /R d:\all\ %%a in (Graphic*.jpg) do call :renfile "%%a"
```

(For testing, I'd be awful tempted to `ECHO` the `ren` command...)

---

For the unstated reset-the-numbering question...

```
set lastdir=:
FOR /R d:\all\    %%a in (Graphic*.jpg) do call :renfile "%%a"
goto :eof

:renfile
if NOT "%lastdir%"=="%~p1" set /a cnt=0&set "lastdir=%~p1"
set /a cnt += 1
set padCnt=0000%cnt%
ren %1 %padCnt:~-4%%~x1
```

(air code - should work)

Comment: yes it works but the problem is that the serial number is not reset for each folder , i want each folder to has its own series of names starting from 0001.jpg  ......

Comment: thank you for your effort but the reset of numbers does not work it still working without resetting the numbers

Comment: Yes - two glitches. First, I'd left the `photos1\ ` in the `FOR /R` and I'd omitted the `NOT` in the `IF` line. fixed now...